Minimal polynomial question (LADR, 4th Ed)
I'm reading the following question from Linear Algebra Done Right (Fourth Edition).

However, I must be misunderstanding something. Take $p$ as the minimal polynomial of T. Then $p(T) = 0$. However, this question implies that there exists a unique $r\in \mathcal{P(F)}$ such that $r(T) = p(T) = 0$ and the degree of $r$ is less than the degree of the minimal polynomial, $p$. But this is a contradiction, since the minimal polynomial is the monic polynomial of lowest order such that $p(T) = 0$, ie there is no such $r$ such that $r(T) = p(T) =0$ with $r$ having lower order. If there were such an $r$, we could make it monic by dividing through by the leading coefficient, yielding new minimal polynomial.
What am I missing?
Thank you!!!

In your example case, $r$ is the zero polynomial.

@AnuragA thank you!

The statement does not say that $r$ must be a monic polynomial, so the fact that the minimal polynomial$~\mu$ is the monic polynomial of minimal degree with a certain property does not exclude that $r$ of strictly less degree with that property; indeed in your example $r=0$ has that property, and by convention the degree of$~0$ is less than that of any other polynomial.
Whenever you see a statement that claims the existence of a unique polynomial of degree less than that of a given polynomial $p$ with a certain property, you should think of using a remainder in euclidean division by$~p$, and this question is no exception.
